# Urlencode list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, urllib

I have dataframe and I have converted it into a list of dictionaries:

```
df = data.to_dict(orient = "records")
```

output:

```
[{'MAIN KITCHEN': 9.6, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:05:00'}, 
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 9.6, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:10:00'}, 
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 9.6, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:15:00'},
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 11.2, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:20:00'}, 
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 11.2, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:25:00'}, 
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 12.8, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:30:00'},
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 9.6, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:35:00'}, 
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 11.2, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:40:00'},
 {'MAIN KITCHEN': 12.8, 'Time': ' 05/01/2017 00:45:00'}]
```

P.S: I want my data like this only.

I want to encode this output into `url` or as a querystring.

i tried this:

```
param = urllib.urlencode(df)
```

But i am getting an error:

```
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

Can someone tell me the correct way to do this?

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: @MedAli, %5B%7B%27MAIN+KITCHEN%27%3A+9.6%2C+%27Time%27%3A+%27+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A05%3A00%27%7D%2C+%0D%0A+%7B%27MAIN+KITCHEN%27%3A+9.6%2C+%27Time%27%3A+%27+05%2F01%2F2017

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you have any questions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the list of dictionaries, and apply `urllib.urlencode` on each one of them.

```
In [46]: [urllib.urlencode(d) for d in df.to_dict(orient='records')]
Out[46]: 
['Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A05%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A10%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A15%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A20%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=11.2',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A25%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=11.2',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A30%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=12.8',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A35%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A40%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=11.2',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A45%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=12.8']
```

---

You can also do this before your convert to dictionary:

```
In [54]: df.apply(lambda x: urllib.urlencode(dict(x)), axis=1) 
Out[54]: 
0    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A05%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
1    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A10%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
2    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A15%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
3    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A20%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
4    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A25%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
5    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A30%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
6    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A35%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
7    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A40%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
8    Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A45%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN...
dtype: object

In [55]: df.apply(lambda x: urllib.urlencode(dict(x)), axis=1).tolist()  
Out[55]: 
['Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A05%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A10%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A15%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A20%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=11.2',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A25%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=11.2',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A30%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=12.8',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A35%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=9.6',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A40%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=11.2',
 'Time=+05%2F01%2F2017+00%3A45%3A00&MAIN+KITCHEN=12.8']
```